# SQL statement to hide all system databases in Server from a server login

Tags: sql-server, permissions, logins, system-databases

I want to create a Windows authentication server login and make it cannot see any system databases e.g.master, model.

I know that we can control view definition in database level e.g. database user, database role but I don't want to configure them to all system databases.

Therefore, I started by:

1. Create Windows authentication login
2. Create custom server role
3. Deny view definition to a custom server role
4. Add an login to a role

I hope the login shouldn't see all system databases but it still can see master and tempdb under System Databases node.

This is the screenshot of the result.

[image]

and these are my SQL statements.

```
-- Create login from Windows User
USE MASTER
GO

CREATE LOGIN [domain\web_user] FROM WINDOWS WITH 
DEFAULT_DATABASE = MyTestDB
GO

USE MyTestDB
GO

CREATE USER web_user FOR LOGIN [domain\web_user]
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo 
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'DB_DataReader', 
@membername = 'web_user'
GO



--Create custom server role, deny view definition and add login to role
USE master
GO

CREATE SERVER ROLE junior
GO 

DENY VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [junior]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE junior ADD MEMBER [domain\web_user] ​
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

From this post [hide system databases sql server management studio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/85868/hide-system-databases-sql-server-management-studio).

I think it solves my problem.
However, for normal login and user, we can't hide master and tempdb database.

The following information are in this document.
[hide system databases sql server management studio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/85868/hide-system-databases-sql-server-management-studio)

> After this permission is denied, a login can see only metadata for
>   master, tempdb, and databases that the login owns.